# Is there a way to target the Field Content Type in Freeform Pro?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

Just wondering if there is a way to target this?

I've got an field in freeform that the field type is set to text and the field content type set to email.

In the front end I'm wishing to target this field specifically.

The same way you can do this : composer:field_type == 'nonfield_title'.

Cant see anything about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that isn't possible (as you mentioned, `field_type` is available, but not field *content* type). I would suggest submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on. :)
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions